# How to update the display properly in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have been learning to react, earlier i have been just calling api in componentDidMount with axios it was working fine.
Now,this task was without getting data from api, therefore i as usual called setState in  componentDidMOunt but since setState is async, it wasn't updated, when i need it.
I want to know how should i write this, in order to mitigate this issue. Here is a simple class code.

```
    import React from 'react'
import CarCapacity from '../Components/TextBox/CarCapacity'
import randomHelper from '../Helper/randomCars'
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row'

class Parking extends React.Component{
    state={
        inText:null,
        cars:100,
        carDetails:[],
        remainingSlots:[]
    }

    numberOfcars=(event)=>{
        this.setState({inText:event.target.value})
    }

    updateFunc = ()=>{
        var details = randomHelper(this.state.cars)

        //setState is async therefore using a callBack to check if the state has been updated

        this.setState({carDetails:{...details}},function(){
            console.log(this.state.carDetails)
        })

    }



componentDidMount(){
    this.updateFunc()
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
    if(prevState.cars!==this.state.cars){
        this.updateFunc()
    }
}

    setToCars=()=>{
        var st= this.state.inText;

        if(this.state.inText==null||st.trim()===""){
            alert("Cars cant be null")
        }
        else if(Number.isNaN(Number(this.state.inText))){
            alert("Enter a number")
        }
        else{
        this.setState({cars:this.state.inText})
        }
    }


    render(){

        console.log(this.state.carDetails)

        var carParkingFormation = this.state.carDetails.map((data, index)=>{
            var isCarParked = data.carNumber!==null? data.carNumber: "Not parked"
            var color = data.carColor!==null? data.carColor:" "
            var pos = data.carPosition

            return(
                <>
                    <Col md={4}>
                        <span>{isCarParked}</span>
                        <span>{color}</span>
                        <span>{pos}</span>
                    </Col>
                </>
            )
        })


        return(
            <>
            <CarCapacity carCapacity={this.numberOfcars} genCars={this.setToCars}/>
            <p>{this.state.cars}</p>
             <Row>
                {carParkingFormation}
             </Row>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default Parking
```

Here, in this carParkingFormation this.state.carDetail is null as setState beig async, so, how can i ensure that it runs properly as the way expected

Comment: I mean, it looks like you're using the setState() callback correctly, are you experiencing different behavior?

Comment: No, the state is updated, however,in the render, the map function is not working. How should i write it, since if i move carParkingFormation in callback, it wont be accessible in render

Comment: Check if it's an array before iterating over it? Default to an empty array? Show some kind of loading state? Actually it looks like you *already* default to an empty array, so when is it null? Give a [mcve]; what's the output? Why do you setState with carDetails as an *object*?

Comment: Yaah, right , i get it , thanks, i have done this like 100 times. Its like mind stopped working now. Sorry for lame question

Comment: Why have you accepted and maybe upvoted an answer that doesn't actually address the problem, then? That's just going to be confusing for anyone else with a similar problem.

Comment: Well after your comment, I realized my mistake, what I was doing wrong, I could easily put the loading thing, but since, he had taken effort to write the answer I upvoted and marked it right (without checking), sorry it's my mistake, I should have checked.

Comment: Aaaaaand, he has deleted the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `carDetails` is an array and you are setting it as an object in `updateFunc` so in that case the map in render will not work on object. Try changing it to below:

```
this.setState({carDetails:[...details]},function(){
            console.log(this.state.carDetails)
        })
```